# Accessing filenames with accents / Unicode in the terminal

Tags: linux, unicode, command-line, terminal

I've got a number of files like:

- Camera.txt
- Cámera.txt
- C我mera.txt

Given that I don't know how to type accented or Chinese characters, how do I access them in the terminal?

Normally, I'd use tab completion when using the terminal in Linux.

```
nano Cam<TAB>
```

Will auto complete the filename (if it exists):

```
nano Camera.txt
```

But there seems no way to do that if I'm unable to type the non-ASCII character.

Output of `locale` is :

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Please mention the character encoding of your terminal so that we may help you accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your locale is set correctly (which effectively means that your locale is an UTF-8 one), there are some ways to access your files, more or less boring:

- if you are using `bash` or other shell that uses GNU readline, follow [this advice](https://superuser.com/questions/627524/how-can-i-iterate-through-possible-completions-in-gnu-readline) to enable Tab completion iteration so that by pressing Tab several times you will be able to select any file matching the given prefix.
- use shell wildcards `*` and `?`. If the `Cámara.txt` is not a misprint (note the second `a`, not `e`), it can be selected as `C?mara.txt`, while the other two don't match this template.
- finally, in most terminals, mouse selection, copy and paste are your friends.

That's all for now, give us more details (at least, the output of `locale` and which shell you are using) to have better advice.

Comment: Although I couldn't get shell wildcards working, I was able to put `TAB: menu-complete` into `~/.inputrc` - that *does* work. Thanks.